# How to extract hostname from the given URL in Python?

Tags: python

How can I extract the hostname from: `hostname:/file_name` ? For example in `ngs.pradhi.com:/upload`, I want to extract `ngs.pradhi.com` from it and test it via ssh.connect.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string in your example isn't a URL, so you won't be able to use the standard URL module (`urlparse`) to parse it. Here is how you can do it by hand:

```
In [43]: path = 'ngs.pradhi.com:/upload'

In [44]: path.split(':')[0]
Out[44]: 'ngs.pradhi.com'
```

For SSH, take a look at [`paramiko`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/).

Comment: What if it is formed like http ://host:8080/etc/etc ?

Comment: @alemangui: There is no such requirement mentioned in the question. I suspect the use of the word "URL" is simply a misnomer. In any event, it would be helpful if the OP clarified this one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using the [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module:

> This module defines a standard interface to break Uniform Resource Locator (URL) strings up in components (addressing scheme, network location, path etc.), to combine the components back into a URL string, and to convert a “relative URL” to an absolute URL given a “base URL.”

Example:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://ngs.pradhi.com/upload')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='ngs.pradhi.com', path='/upload', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: In Python 3, [this is now](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) in the `urllib.parse` module, so either `import urllib.parse` and use with `urllib.parse.urlparse(my_url)` or import  `from urllib.parse import urlparse` and use with `urlparse(my_url)`